# Add a column to multilevel nested structure in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe with below structure.

Current Schema:

```
root
 |-- ID
 |-- Information
 |   |-- Name
 |   |-- Age
 |   |-- Gender
 |-- Description
```

I would like to add first name and last name to Information.Name

Is there a way to add new columns so multi level struct types in pyspark?

Expected Schema:

```
root
 |-- ID
 |-- Information
 |   |-- Name
 |   |   |-- firstName
 |   |   |-- lastName
 |   |-- Age
 |   |-- Gender
 |-- Description
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `withField`, this would work:

```
df=df.withColumn('Information', F.col('Information').withField('Name', F.struct(*[F.col('Information.Name').alias('FName'), F.lit('').alias('LName')])))
```

Schema Before:

```
root
 |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Information: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Age: integer (nullable = true)
```

Schema After:

```
root
 |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Information: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Name: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- FName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- LName: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- Age: integer (nullable = true)
```

I initialized the value of Fname with the current value of Name, you can use substring if that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If all Names follow below pattern then you can split on whitespace.

```
FirstName LastName
```

Example code with data.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as sqlf

data = [{
   "ID":1,
   "Information":{
      "Name":"Alice Wonderland",
      "Age":20,
      "Gender":"Female"
   },
   "Description":"Test data"
}]
  
schema = StructType([
            StructField("Description", StringType(), True),
            StructField("ID", IntegerType(), True),
            StructField("Information",
                StructType([
                    StructField("Name", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("Age", IntegerType(), True),
                    StructField("Gender", StringType(), True)
                ]),True)
         ])
 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema)

splitName = sqlf.split(df.Information.Name,' ')

df=df.withColumn('Information', sqlf.col('Information')
.withField('Name', sqlf.struct(splitName[0].alias('firstName'), splitName[1].alias('lastName'))))

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- Description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Information: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Name: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- firstName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- lastName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Age: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Gender: string (nullable = true)

df.show(truncate=False)
+-----------+---+---------------------------------+
|Description|ID |Information                      |
+-----------+---+---------------------------------+
|Test data  |1  |{{Alice, Wonderland}, 20, Female}|
+-----------+---+---------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, Unpacking and repacking struct columns, Like below.

```
df.withColumn(
  "Information", 
   expr(
   '''
      STRUCT(
        NAMED_STRUCT(
           'firstName', 
           '', 
           'lastName', 
           ''
        ) AS Name,
        Information.Age, 
        Information.Gender
      )
   ''')
)
```